# how to get the difference of two points in a 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, difference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int c;
    int distance=0;
    int largestdistance=0;
    int sum=0;
    cin >> c;
    int point[c][2];
    for (int i=0; i<c; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            cin >> point[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << point[2][0] << " ";
    for (int i=0; i<c; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            sum += abs(point[0][0]-point[1][0])+abs(point[0][1]-point[1][1]);
        }
        if (sum > largestdistance){
            largestdistance=sum;
        }
        cout << '\n';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This program prints out the value of the absolute value of the first row first number minus the second row first number added to the absolute value of the first row second number minus the second row second number. I was wondering that how do I make the program so that it automatically does the `sum += abs(point[0][0]-point[1][0])+abs(point[0][1]-point[1][1])` for all `point[][]` all the way up to `sum += abs(point[c-1][0]-point[c][0])+abs(point[c-1][1]-point[c][1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a lot clearer if you introduced a point type:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

int manhattan_dist(const Point& p, const Point& q) {
    return abs(p.x - q.x) + abs(p.y - q.y);
}
```

Armed with that, it's a lot easier to loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < c - 1; ++i) {  // stop before c-1, so i and i+1 are valid
    sum += manhattan_dist(points[i], points[i+1]);
}
```

Btw `int point[c][2];` is non-standard code because `c` is not a compile-time constant. You need to dynamically allocate the array:

```
Point* points = new Point[c];
```

or, preferably:

```
std::vector<Point> points(c);
```

Comment: Then do I have to dynamically allocate the array to make the program work, or is it optional? @Barry

Comment: @SeanChen Your compiler *may* let you do it. But it would be better not to rely on non-C++11 features (VLAs are just for C). Just dynamically allocate the memory.

Comment: Um, but I am using a really old version of C++, not C++ 11, so I might not be able to do that.

Comment: I right now changed everything that you told me and I updated my code so that it has your stuff in it. But, for some reason I have an error with the cin>>points[i][j]; The error is no match for 'operator[]' in '(&points)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = Point, _Alloc = 
 std::allocator<Point>](((unsigned int)i))[j]'. Do you know how to fix this. @Barry

Comment: @SeanChen Because `points` is not a 2D array anymore, it's a 1D array of `Point`. You'll have to input the `x` and the `y` separately.

Comment: How do I input the x and y separately now since x and y are not defined in the int main? @Barry